# Files (e.g. music) on secondary drive can't be found by programs

Tags: filesystems, dual-boot, elementary-os

I'm dual booting elementary OS with Windows 10. Each has its main file system on a 128gb SSD, with shared data on a 1TB HDD.

I can access and use files on the HDD perfectly fine through the file browser, but as soon as I try to access/use them through a program (e.g. Noise music player) the files can't be found (in the case of an import location) or the HDD itself doesn't exist in file-selection dialogues (only / and /home)

What is going on and what's the correct way to fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with elementary OS, but does your file browser show the path to the HDD? Otherwise you can try `/media/`, `/media/<your_username>` or `/run/media/<your_username>`.

Comment: While your question is on-topic here, it is more likely to get good answers on [elementaryos.se], because it requires knowledge of elementary OS's interface. (I think Sparhawk's comment is on the right track, but as neither of us is familiar with elementary, we could be missing something.) If you don't get anwers here, you may delete your question here and post it on [elementaryos.se] instead.